# fetchmail issue:fetching multiple account

Tags: linux, email

I have a fetchmail install in my linux machine.
Here are the configuration in my .fetchmailrc

```
 set logfile /root/fetchmail.log
 ##set daemon 300


 poll smtp.gmail.com proto imap
 user "mygmail@gmail.com" pass "mypass1" is "root" here


 poll smtp.gmail.com proto imap
 user "mygmail2@gmail.com" pass "mypass2" is "root" here

 ssl
 fetchall
 no keep
 mda "/usr/bin/procmail -f %F -d %T";
```

I want to fetch from both account but when i run fetchmail -kv , it only fetching the second gmail.I've already modified my fetchmailrc based on  man fetchmail.But still no use.Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally found solution for my problems.It seems that some changes need to be done in .fetchmailrc.To get the fetchmail working,modify the .fetchmailrc as below:

```
set postmaster "root"
set bouncemail
set logfile /root/fetchmail.log

poll pop.gmail.com proto pop3
  user 'youremail1@gmail.com' there with password 'paswd' is root here options ssl
  user 'youremail2@gmail.com' there with password 'paswd' is root here options ssl


fetchall
no keep
mda "/usr/bin/procmail -f %F -d %T";
```

Please note that the settings might be different based on your requirement.But these code have the basic settings to keep fetchmail running.Hope this help for whoever getting stuck with the same problem.